# how to delete a connection in draw2d?

Tags: javascript, draw2d-js

I want to know how I delete a connection in draw2d. I tried disconnect() method but dose not seems to be work. This is my code

```
menu.appendMenuItem(new draw2d.MenuItem("Disconnect", null, function() {
        //draw2d.Connection.workflow.removeFigure(draw2d.Connection.prototype);
        var cmd =  new draw2d.CommandDelete(oThis);
        oThis.workflow.getCommandStack().excute(cmd);
    }));
```

here oThis is of type "draw2d.Connection".
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever open the firebug error console?

PLEASE check this before you create every day a lot of messages

Replace "excute" with "execute" and everythingis working well.

...sorry for this ....butIhaveread your other postings and I think you didn' try to solve your problems first by open the examples,jsdoc or the error console.

Comment: Thanks Friend for your suggestions. But before opening any example i m trying it hard. But still i am somewhere lacking. So I will take your post Positively!!